# What is the precision of the bash builtin time command?

Tags: linux, bash, performance, time

I have a script that measures the execution time of a program using the bash builtin command `time`.

I am trying to understand the precision of this command: as far as I know it returns the precision in ms, however it use the `getrusage()` function which returns a value in microseconds. But reading [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.111.4907&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the real precision is only of 10ms because `getrusage` samples the time relying on ticks (= 100Hz). The paper is really old (it mentions Linux 2.2.14 running on a Pentium 166Mhz with 96Mb of ram).

Is `time` still using `getrusage()` and 100 Hz ticks or is more precise on modern systems?

The testing machine is running Linux 2.6.32.

**EDIT**: This is a slightly modified version (which should compile also on old version of GCC) of **muru's code**: modify the value of variable 'v' change also the delay between measures in order to spot the minimum granularity. A value around 500,000 should trigger changes of 1ms on a relatively recent cpu (first versions of i5/i7 @~2.5Ghz)

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void dosomething(){
    long v = 1000000; 
        while (v > 0)
          v--;
}

int main()
{
    struct rusage r1, r2;
    long t1, t2, min, max;
    int i;

    printf("t1\tt2\tdiff\n");

    for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
        getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r1);
        dosomething();
        getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r2);

        t1 = r1.ru_stime.tv_usec + r1.ru_stime.tv_sec*1000000 + r1.ru_utime.tv_usec + r1.ru_utime.tv_sec*1000000;
        t2 = r2.ru_stime.tv_usec + r2.ru_stime.tv_sec*1000000 + r2.ru_utime.tv_usec + r2.ru_utime.tv_sec*1000000;

        printf("%ld\t%ld\t%ld\n",t1,t2,t2-t1);

        if ((t2-t1 < min) | (i == 0))
            min = t2-t1;

        if ((t2-t1 > max) | (i == 0))
            max = t2-t1;
        dosomething();

    }

    printf("Min = %ldus Max = %ldus\n",min,max);

    return 0;
}
```

However the precision is bound to linux version: with Linux 3 and above the precision is in the order of us, while on linux 2.6.32 could be around 1ms, probably depending also on the specific distro. I suppose that this difference is related to the usage of HRT isntead of Tick on recent linux versions.

In any case the maximum precision of time is 1ms on all recent and not-so-recent machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bash` builtin `time` still uses `getrusage(2)`. On an Ubuntu 14.04 system:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ strace -o log bash -c 'time sleep 1'

real    0m1.018s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.001s
$ tail log
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 0}, ru_stime={0, 3242}, ...}) = 0
getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, {ru_utime={0, 0}, ru_stime={0, 530}, ...}) = 0
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
write(2, "real\t0m1.018s\n", 14)        = 14
write(2, "user\t0m0.000s\n", 14)        = 14
write(2, "sys\t0m0.001s\n", 13)         = 13
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

As the `strace` output shows, it calls `getrusage`.

As for precision, the `rusage` struct that `getrusage` uses includes `timeval` objects, and `timeval` has microsecond precision. From the [manpage of `getrusage`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html):

```
ru_utime
      This is the total amount of time spent executing in user mode,
      expressed in a timeval structure (seconds plus microseconds).

ru_stime
      This is the total amount of time spent executing in kernel
      mode, expressed in a timeval structure (seconds plus
      microseconds).
```

I think it does better than 10 ms. Take the following example file:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct rusage now, then;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &then);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &now);
    printf("%ld %ld\n",
        then.ru_stime.tv_usec + then.ru_stime.tv_sec*1000000 + then.ru_utime.tv_usec + then.ru_utime.tv_sec*1000000
        now.ru_stime.tv_usec + now.ru_stime.tv_sec*1000000 + now.ru_utime.tv_usec + now.ru_utime.tv_sec*1000000);
}
```

Now:

```
$ make test
cc     test.c   -o test
$ for ((i=0; i < 5; i++)); do ./test; done
447 448
356 356
348 348
347 347
349 350
```

The reported differences between successive calls to `getrusage` are 1 µs and 0 (the minimum). Since it does show a 1 µs gap, the tick must be at most 1 µs.

If it had a 10 ms tick, the differences would be zero, or at least 10000.

Comment: Thanks, seems reasonable. Looking at my old notes about RTOS seems that Linux tick can be configured at 100, 250 and 1000Hz furthermore exists High Resolution Timer which are more precise than 1 ms.

Maybe I miss something but I think you should multiply by 1,000,000 because 1s = 10^-6s

However for my purpose I can assume the maximum precision reported by time (1ms)

Comment: @AlessandroValentini Oops. That's what comes of reusing testing code. :D

Comment: In any case it does not affect the test until you run short programs ;)

Comment: Hi, I have run your test on my laptop and it works perfectly, then I tried it on the machine we use for the test but it always return 0 0. My machine runs Fedora 22 (Linux 4.0.4) while the desktop runs Red Hat 6 (kernel 2.6.32), have you any idea about this strange behaviour? the two machines should have very close performance in single thread

Comment: @AlessandroValentini Your laptop's running which kernel? I'm on a 3.13 something.

Comment: Sorry I hit enter by mistake, more info are in the edit

Comment: I have added some "active delay" (a loop that calculate var--) between the two getrusage() and the minimum interval I am able to measure is  1000us+/-1us, when I try to go under this threshold the difference falls to 0. So probably: 1) my machine still use Tick@1000Hz instead of HRT 2) very close measures are taken in the same tick so they will not found any difference. So in any case time has a precision of 1ms, however an identical machine with RHEL7 (Linux 3.10) the experiments works fine with a precision in us. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @AlessandroValentini Yes, I can reproduce your results on a 2.6.32 Ubuntu 10.04 system. :/ Looks like you need something else for that old a kernel.